# sql join same tables on multiple unique keys

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries that i am attempting to get the results side by side so i can do a comparison.

When I do a sub-query i get error duplicate data. the problem is I am joining the same tables in two different unique keys, to get the unique data.

Results I want is

```
Tw | W 
=======================


SELECT W.category AS 'TW'
FROM   W,R
WHERE  W.wc=R.tw 



SELECT  W.category AS 'W'
FROM R,W
WHERE  W.wc=R.wc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a highly-sanitized query and thus no information on what W and R are, I have to do a little mind reading. What I think you want is to compare, side-by-side, the category of two records in W that are cross-referenced through R using R.wc and R.tw. That's not difficult:

```
SELECT R.id, TW.Category as TW, WC.Category as W
FROM R
JOIN W as TW ON TW.wc = R.tw
JOIN W AS WC ON WC.wc = R.wc
```

If you really don't care about R except as the cross-reference between two records in W, then just drop the first column from the select list, and you'll get the two columns you want.